# grakn 1.0.0 cannot start queue on debian/wheezy with jdk8

Tags: java-8, debian, vaticle-typedb

I installed grakn 1.0.0 on debian/wheezy with jdk8

while starting grakn server it says

STORAGE .... STARTED
QUEUE ..... FAILED

I found nothing useful in the log directory.

any clues where I could look or where I could ask will
be appreciated

thanks, Gerald

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. After failing to start, it created a file (like hs_err_pid20005.log) that said:

```
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 3720347648 bytes for committing reserved memory.
```

Seems like it's looking for ~3.7GB ! After freeing up some memory, it started fine for me.

Comment: And where did it create this file? Under `grakn/logs/`?

Comment: It was actually in the root grakn/ folder