# Not able to start grakn, Storage is not able to start

Tags: vaticle-typedb, vaticle-typeql

I have installed grakn on unix and earlier it was working fine but now giving issues as it is not able to start.

I tried to run it using below command:

```
./grakn server start
```

Getting below error.

```
Starting Storage-FAILED!
Unable to start Storage
Please run 'grakn server status' or check the logs located under 'logs' directory.
```

Comment: And what did the status command and logs tell you?

Comment: Please see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48844718/grakn-1-0-0-cannot-start-queue-on-debian-wheezy-with-jdk8

Comment: For me it wasn't the memory issue, but I can't tell what it was. I completely reinstalled the whole Ubuntu and now I'm avoiding to stop Grakn.

Answer (score 1):

There may be lot of things happening under the hood. Without looking into logs this is hard to tell what exactly happening. You can try killing all the processes and then remove associate pids from `/tmp/` directory. Then retry starting grakn server.

```
$ for KILLPID in `ps ax | grep 'grakn' | awk '{print $1}'`; do kill -9 $KILLPID; done

$ ps -ef | grep defunct | grep -v grep | cut -b8-20 | xargs kill -9

$ rm -rf /tmp/grakn-*
```

Let me know if it helps.